# Trigger function on $(window).resize and $("#foo").scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would like to trigger the same function on $(window).resize and on $("#foo").scroll.

http://jsfiddle.net/ySukf/1/

Need `#stick` to stick to the top of `#foo`. The problem is that the position of `#stick` gets a bit jumpy when scrolling and when resizing the window. Any help?

Comment: I don't quite understand what your `#anchor` div does...

Comment: @Eric The `#anchor` div is there to push down the content (by an amount equal to the height of `#stick`) when `#stick` is taken out of the text flow by `position: fixed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's a solution](http://jsfiddle.net/vQKAt/1/)

First, we add two more containers - a `.content` div inside `#foo`, and an `.inner` div inside `#stick`:

```
<div id="foo">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <div id="stick">
            <div class="inner">stick</div>
        </div>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Note that `#anchor` is gone.

The css for the container gets split in half:

```
#foo {
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
#foo .content {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

And we apply the following to the `#stick`. The inner box inherits its size from the outer one.

```css
#stick {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
#stick .inner {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    background: pink;
}
#stick.stuck .inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Almost everything is take care of in css - the javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#foo .content").scroll(stickyTop);
    $(window).resize(stickyTop);
});

function stickyTop() {
    //position is now relative to #foo
    if ($("#stick").position().top < 0)
        $("#stick").addClass('stuck');
    else
        $('#stick').removeClass('stuck');
}​
```

Comment: BTW this was what I needed it for: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1435947/so/i/index.html

Comment: Nice, that was my end-solution too, but this looks cleaner :)